# How to change default camera behavior when marker is tapped?

Tags: google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

In release 1.2 of the Google Maps for iOS SDK the default behavior of a tapped marker changed.
The release note says: "The default behavior when a marker is tapped has been updated to also pan the camera to the marker's position"

How can I get the old behavior back, i.e. not panning the camera center to the position of the marker?

Answer (score 17):

Add the following method to your GMSMapView delegate implementation. GMSMapView will no longer center on the selected marker and brings back the existing behavior.

```
- (BOOL) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {
     mapView.selectedMarker = marker;
     return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for this answer and was hard to find. It works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
mapView.selectedMarker = nil

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        mapView.selectedMarker = nil
        return true
}
```