# How to prevent camera from moving when tapping marker in Google Maps?

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using Google Maps SDK for iOS. I want to prevent the camera from moving when I tap a marker. How can I make it?

Answer (score 6):

Add the following code in your viewDidLoad

```
- (BOOL) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {
     mapView.selectedMarker = marker;
     return TRUE;
}
```

Credits

[How to change default camera behavior when marker is tapped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084944/how-to-change-default-camera-behavior-when-marker-is-tapped?rq=1)